# How to detect integer overflow?

Tags: c++

> 8. Write a program that reads and stores a series of integers and then computes the sum of the first N integers. First ask for N, then read
>    the values into a vector, then calculate the sum of the first N
>    values. For example: “Please enter the number of values you want to
>    sum:” 3 “Please enter some integers (press '|' to stop):” 12 23 13 24
>    15 | “The sum of the first 3 numbers ( 12 23 13 ) is 48.” Handle all
>    inputs. For example, make sure to give an error message if the user
>    asks for a sum of more numbers than there are in the vector.
> 9. Modify the program from exercise 8 to write out an error if the result cannot be represented as an int.

So in exercise 9 it says to write out an error message if the result cannot be represented as an int, but if I'm only adding up integers here the only thing I can think of here that would cause a number to not be able to be represented as an int would be if there's some integer overflow and the integer goes above *INT_MAX* or below *INT_MIN* but how exactly can I detect this?

This is my code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int N = 0;
        vector<int> values;
        cout << "Please enter the number of values you want to sum." << '\n';
        cin >> N;
        cout << "Please enter some numbers" << '\n';
        for (int tempnum; cin >> tempnum; )
        {
    
            values.push_back(tempnum);
    
    
        }
        if (N > values.size())
        {
    
            cout << "How am I gonna add up more numbers than you gave me?" << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                total += values[i];
            }
            
    
        }
    
    }
```

But I can't just check if total is above or below INT_MAX or INT_MIN because *INT_MAX* +1 or something returns some random negative value so I'm not really sure how to do this

Comment: Note that the question says `integers` and not `int`.  So you are not restricted to using `int` in the computations.  If on your system `long` is larger than an `int` you can use this and check the result of each addition against the maximum possible `int`.

Comment: But then right after exercise 9 in exercise 10 it says: 10. Modify the program from exercise 8 to use double instead of int.
Also, make a vector of doubles containing the N–1 differences
between adjacent values and write out that vector of differences. Which I'm gonna assume basically means that I do have to use ints in 8 and 9.

Comment: duplicates: [How to catch integer overflow in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7451207/995714), [automatic overflow detection in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865443/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some arithmetic:

So you want to know if `acc + x > INT_MAX`, where `acc` is the accumulator (the sum so far) and `x` is the next element. Adding them together may overflow though. But `acc > INT_MAX - x` is equivalent and x is already stored in an `int`. So this can also not *underflow*, bc. `x` can be at most `INT_MAX`.

I.e., just transform the inequation to avoid overflow. In this case, subtract x from both sides.

That only works for positive x though, thanks to user interjay for pointing this out.

With negative x, this becomes a subtraction:

```
acc + (-x) > INT_MAX
acc - x    > INT_MAX
```

This can not overflow, because we are subtracting from `acc`. But it may *underflow*, so the question becomes:

```
acc - x < INT_MIN
acc     < INT_MIN + x
```

So:

```
int acc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int x = values[i];
    if (x >= 0 && acc > (INT_MAX - x)) {
        cout << "ERROR: Overflow.";
        return 1;
    } else if (x < 0 && acc < (INT_MIN - x)) {
        cout << "ERROR: Underflow.";
        return 1;
    } else {
        acc += x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This can overflow if `x < 0`. You'd need to handle negative `x` differently.

Comment: Ah dang, good point

Comment: Intmin plus a negative number always underflows. There is a typo in your second if.